# How to add iOS Storyboard to an existing C++ project

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, qt

Working with an existing Qt Xcode project implemented in C++. Therefore the application launches by the execution of the main

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

How can I add a Storyboard as an initial View Controller under iOS? I suppose I have to change the `main.cpp` into a `main.mm` and invoke the Storyboard instead of the `MainWindow`?!?

Normally each Objective-C or Swift project has it's own Application Delegate, which doesn't exists inside a C++ Xcode project.

EDIT: Another and maybe the easiest solution is to create a new Swift/Objective-C project and include the C++ Xcode project.

Comment: I think you suppose to add your cpp files into objective c project. because you need a view controller Class to hold a view that you would create on story board. and I think there is no concept  of UIVIEWCONTROLER in c++;

Comment: The project is really large and difficult to handle. Therefore I would prefer another solution.